# How to get the frequency of occurrence of a column as a percent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**I have a dataset, df,  that looks similar to this:**

```
houses    price
ranch     300,000
ranch     350,000
ranch     400,000
condo     250,000
condo     275,000
townhome  300,000
```

I would like to groupby the different categories within the 'houses' column and display the percentage of each category

**Desired output**

```
houses      percent
ranch       50%
condo       33%
townhome    16.60%
```

**This is what I am doing:**

```
percent is part/whole


df1 = df.groupby['houses'].sum()    #df1 gives us the sum
percent = df1.['houses']/df1
```

However, I am not retaining both columns houses and percent
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You need to change the way the data is being read. `'price'` is not a number. If you're reading from a csv with `.read_csv()`, then use the `thousands=','` parameter.

Comment: Ok thank you @TrentonMcKinney

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the unique values with `value_counts` and use the `normalize` parameter:

```
df['houses'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

ranch       50.000000
condo       33.333333
townhome    16.666667
Name: houses, dtype: float64
```

Edit: to convert to a DataFrame:

```
(df['houses'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100).to_frame()
```

Answer (score 2):

Groupby version:

```
>>> df.groupby('houses').count() / len(df) * 100

              price
houses             
condo     33.333333
ranch     50.000000
townhome  16.666667
```